# How long does mongod need to shut down? (seems > 1 min, which can lead to db corruption)

Tags: mongodb

We run mongodb 2.6.4 on Win2012.
(log says "2014-12-23T02:04:07.711-0600 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2" but the OS is Win2012)

We recently had an OS reboot, during a scheduled maint window, for patch application.
This has happened many times no problem.

This time, however, monngodb would not come back up, as the db/journal was toast.

Why was it toast?

An examination of the log below shows 68 seconds from mongod getting the OS shutdown command, and mongo is still cleaning up. After 68 seconds, the OS terminated mongod.

After the reboot, mongod would not come up, which started a huge fire drill, resulted in lost data, and worse.

What do we do to make mongo a little less fragile?

```
2015-01-27T02:02:48.633-0600 [conn14432] insert log4net_mongodb.LogItem ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:278756 278ms
2015-01-27T02:02:49.850-0600 [conn14432] insert log4net_mongodb.LogItem ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:295554 295ms
2015-01-27T02:02:49.990-0600 CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT signal
2015-01-27T02:02:49.990-0600 [consoleTerminate] got CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT, will terminate after current cmd ends
2015-01-27T02:02:50.006-0600 [consoleTerminate] now exiting
2015-01-27T02:02:50.006-0600 [consoleTerminate] dbexit: 
2015-01-27T02:02:50.006-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-01-27T02:02:50.021-0600 [consoleTerminate] closing listening socket: 1840
2015-01-27T02:02:50.021-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-01-27T02:02:50.021-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-01-27T02:02:50.021-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14429] end connection 192.168.99.231:58970 (8 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14428] end connection 192.168.99.226:52203 (8 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14435] end connection 192.168.150.228:60526 (6 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14431] end connection 10.179.228.169:61654 (5 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14437] end connection 192.168.150.112:55376 (4 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14434] end connection 10.209.160.113:50213 (3 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14436] end connection 192.168.150.112:55370 (2 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [conn14433] end connection 10.209.160.115:56479 (8 connections now open)
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-01-27T02:02:50.037-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: final commit...
2015-01-27T02:02:50.162-0600 [conn14432] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [10.209.160.114:53646] 
2015-01-27T02:02:52.112-0600 [consoleTerminate] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-01-27T02:02:54.374-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 6/307    1%  (files)
2015-01-27T02:02:56.752-0600 [serviceShutdown] got SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN request from Windows Service Control Manager, already in shutdown
2015-01-27T02:02:57.684-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 7/307    2%  (files)
2015-01-27T02:02:59.432-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 15/307   4%  (files)
2015-01-27T02:03:01.491-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 20/307   6%  (files)
2015-01-27T02:03:03.316-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 24/307   7%  (files)
2015-01-27T02:03:05.141-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 30/307   9%  (files)
2015-01-27T02:03:07.356-0600 [consoleTerminate]         File Closing Progress: 37/307   12% (files)
```

{mongo is terminated by OS at this point}

Comment: Side note: You might be interested in mongodb mms to handle all your production management of the mongodb clusters. https://mms.mongodb.com/